# ngModel not displaying it's value

Tags: angularjs

I have come across an odd bug where after I change the bject containing data in the component's controller, the input field (ex. `ng-model="taxiCtrl.localTaxi.dest"`) goes blank. The important part is that I initially though that the value is blank but when I set a `console.log($scope.taxiCtrl.localTaxi.dest);` on a random button, after I clicked it the value was there, but the field was blank. Is there any reason why angular would be displaying blanks instead of actual values?

On the component controller's side the changes are happening here:

```
ctrl.$onChanges = function (changes) {
        if (changes.taxi) {
            console.log("change recieved");
            console.log(changes.taxi);
            ctrl.localTaxi = angular.copy(changes.taxi.currentValue);
            console.log(ctrl.localTaxi);
        }
    };
```

The most confusing part is there are 2 situations with the following logs:

1)

```
change recieved
taxi-select-item-controller.js:20 JbcurrentValue: Taxicar: "Green Clown Car"comp: "666"dest: "Botanica"id: "6663"number: ""psngrs: Array[1]time: "23:20"__proto__: ObjectpreviousValue: Taxicar: "Black Cadillac"comp: "111"dest: "Botanica"id: "121"number: ""psngrs: Array[1]time: "12:10"__proto__: Object__proto__: Object
taxi-select-item-controller.js:22 Taxicar: "Green Clown Car"comp: "666"dest: "Botanica"id: "6663"number: ""psngrs: Array[1]time: "23:20"__proto__: Objectconstructor: Taxi(taxi)__proto__: Object
taxi-select-item-controller.js:19
```

2)

```
    change recieved
taxi-select-item-controller.js:20 JbcurrentValue: Taxicar: "Green Clown Car"comp: "666"dest: "Botanica"id: "127"number: ""psngrs: Array[2]0: "just"1: "DO_IT"length: 2__proto__: Array[0]time: "23:20"__proto__: ObjectpreviousValue: Taxicar: "Black Cadillac"comp: "111"dest: "Botanica"id: "121"number: ""psngrs: Array[1]time: "12:10"__proto__: Object__proto__: Object
taxi-select-item-controller.js:22 Taxicar: "Green Clown Car"comp: "666"dest: "Botanica"id: "127"number: ""psngrs: Array[2]time: "23:20"__proto__: Object
taxi-select-item-controller.js:19
```

Where the objects recieved by the controller are the same, but the first instance shows the new object's data in the ngModels, while the second instance shows blanks.

Comment: Could you provide a [mcve]? :)

Answer (score 0):

Check the type of data that input type is using and type of data you are providing if they are of different types this might happen.

Comment: All of the data is just strings and the inut type is text. I even tried change it to String(itself), but that didn't change anything, I assume because for angular that doesn't qualify as a change, since if I add a non-empty string to it, then it will display the proper value.

Comment: please provide a jsfiddle sample